# Are there examples of short-circuit control flow in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, control-flow, short-circuiting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation says "Short-circuit operators are, in effect, control structures" and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_language_structure#Control_structures says "Short-circuit logical operators are commonly used to affect control flow at the expression level", with a pseudo code example directly from the latter being:

```
expr && expr
```

I've seen the above sort of thing recommended in the book [Minimal Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394508).  So why not in Javascript?  Yesterday I wrote something such as the following:

```
myModule && myModule.myMethod(); //instead of if (myModule) myModule.myMethod();
```

Does anybody know of any other examples of usage of this idiom in Javascript, perhaps from open source frameworks?  What might be it's disadvantages, if any (besides, "somebody might not understand it")?

Comment: myModule && myModule.myMethod && myModule.myMethod() is safer...
-or fun stuff like- var c=myModule, c=c.myMethod || String; c()

Comment: Point taken though at some point you just have to trust that your own code will work as expected (for example even your example could be improved with a test to ensure myModule is a function).  I was inquiring more generally, though why I had the need to check for a module is that I have code that only conditionally includes the javascript file containing the module in certain environments (not production, yet)

Comment: This sort of thing is in Perl because it's in shells. If Perl has it, it probably stole it from something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React conditional rendering can be achieved inline with the logical && operator, see https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator  Here's the pertinent snippet (my inline observations are not meant critically, checking length is the smallest and most understandable for a sample):

```
  return (
    // Don't directly check length, instead 
    // consider a more flexible "shouldRender" method
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      {unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
        <h2>
          You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
        </h2>
      }
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

`myModule && myModule.myMethod()` works in JavaScript. But since ECMAScript 2020, there is something better: [Optional Chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
myModule?.myMethod()
```